# Notepad++ Find/Replace Wildcard problems

Tags: regex, replace, find, notepad++, wildcard

Hopefully this is simple because I can't seem to figure it out.

I have a game that outputs a log with information I'd like to review, but it's bogged with tags.

```
<color=#9B9B9BFF>abndnd_b9o66v</color>.<color=#1EFF00FF>out_ys0a67</color>
<color=#9B9B9BFF>uknown_ospiw8</color>.<color=#1EFF00FF>p_vyuxzb</color>
<color=#9B9B9BFF>anonymous_yzgoqq</color>.<color=#1EFF00FF>pub_info_o1rotu</color>
<color=#9B9B9BFF>unidentified_t7stef</color>.<color=#1EFF00FF>out_gems04</color>
<color=#9B9B9BFF>abndnd_5vs06o</color>.<color=#1EFF00FF>public_7gshh2</color>
<color=#9B9B9BFF>anon_7kq2k4</color>.<color=#1EFF00FF>pub_wxn46t</color>
<color=#9B9B9BFF>anon_i83kkg</color>.<color=#1EFF00FF>info_ev39gs</color>
```

I can simply filter it by hand, but I know a regex may be able to help, I just can't seem to figure out the syntax correctly and how to trim the tags without tampering with the needed text

and my end result I'm trying to get is this:

```
abndnd_b9o66v.out_ys0a67
uknown_ospiw8.p_vyuxzb
anonymous_yzgoqq.pub_info_o1rotu
unidentified_t7stef.out_gems04
abndnd_5vs06o.public_7gshh2
anon_7kq2k4.pub_wxn46t
anon_i83kkg.info_ev39gs
```

Comment: So you just want to ignore all elements? If so replace `</?[^>]+>` with nothing. (assumes you never have `<` or `>` in the plain text. PHP version `echo strip_tags($string);`.

Comment: Thank you @chris85 , yours works just as great. I would have never been able to string this together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<color=.*?>(.*?)</color>\.<color=.*?>(.*?)</color>
```

Replace by this:

```
\1\.\2
```

Comment: Esacpe the `.` in the search string.

Comment: As he pointed notepadd++, I didn't need to escape it...  but escaping is good i know :) Done

Comment: Thanks, this really helps me, I have millions of lines like these, I was trying to use ".*?" and "(.*?)" but I wasn't working what i was typing in, thanks so much.

Comment: I will, I have a timer saying I have to wait for some reason before marking an answer. Thank you @Maverick_Mrt

Comment: Yes, you never need to escape `.` **but** if it is not escaped it can be any character except a new line. You shouldnt need to escape it on the replace.